# Removing dynamically created content after animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to make a notification appear, disappear and then remove itself from the DOM after it is finished.

I have tried the following:

```
var minibasketAlert = function (uid, desc) {
  $('.minibasket-alerts').append($('<div class="minibasket-alert" id="'+uid+'-alert"><p>Adding '+desc+' to basket</p></div>'));
  $('#' + uid + '-alert').fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#' + uid + '-alert').remove();
  });
};
```

This adds the item to DOM and fades it and out however it does not remove from the DOM when it is finished

I have also tried:

```
var minibasketAlert = function (uid, desc) {
  $('.minibasket-alerts').append($('<div class="minibasket-alert" id="'+uid+'-alert"><p>Adding '+desc+' to basket</p></div>'));
  $('#' + uid + '-alert').fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
};
```

This removes the newly added element from the DOM before any animation effects take place. I can see the parent element flashing in the inspector when I run the function but nothing displays in the viewport

Comment: What happend if you remove the element outside of the callback function ?

Comment: Then it will be removed before the animation even has a chance to execute. This would be the case even if the element wasn't added dynamically

https://jsfiddle.net/8zmbq39a/

Comment: @Richie the remove function is in callabck function

Comment: Can you reproduce your problem here as a snippet or as a fiddle? Your code seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/bxt23vjr/1/

Comment: I do try not to ask [XY questions](http://xyproblem.info/) but I fear I may be guilty of it this time. My minibasketAlert function is being called in a beforeSend as part of an ajax call. I guess I will need to try isolate my problem somewhere else and update this thread when I find the issue.

Comment: Appears to be working for me. I think I may have just had a browser caching issue. Though I'm reasonably confident I did empty cache and hard reload a few times before posting the question here. I'll not delete the thread, for posterity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var minibasketAlert = function (uid, desc) {
    $('.minibasket-alerts').append($('<div class="minibasket-alert" id="'+uid+'-alert"><p>Adding '+desc+' to basket</p></div>'));
    $('#' + uid + '-alert').fadeIn('fast').delay(2000).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#' + uid + '-alert').remove();
    });
};
```

Was the correct option of the two